# Why is this overflow wrap breaking my alignment for post boxes?

Tags: php, css

My website has two different types of user posts at the moment.  Posts that contain just text and posts that contain text and a single photo.  The user page displays both kinds of posts within a div class called postbox which uses "display: inline-block" so the posts stay in a straight line until the page width ends. Once the page width ends, the next posts continue aligning underneath the previous posts and the cycle continues until there aren't any more posts to display.

Like this..

```
Post 1 Post 2 Post 3
Post 4 Post 5 Post 6
Post 7 Post 8 Post 9
```

When a post's text has a bigger width than the postbox container, I would like the text to wrap until it reaches the max-height of the postbox and then I would like the text to use "text-overflow: ellipsis" to hide the rest of the text.

My problem starts here.  When the text actually is longer than the width of the postbox, I am able to contain the text within the postbox using "overflow-wrap: break-word", however the following postbox will be lowered by the exact width of the new lines created by the overflow wrap.  This lowering effect is undesired and I would like all postboxes on their row to start at the same height.

When the text wraps, my post boxes look like this..

```
Post 1 Post 2
              Post 3
Post 4 Post 5 Post 6
Post 7
       Post 8 Post 9
```

When I remove "overflow-wrap: break-word" The text will continue outside of the postbox, but the postboxes after will correctly stay at the same starting height for their row.

My CSS

```
    .postbox {
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 4px;
        background-color: #555;
        border-radius: 4px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .postbox p {
        width: 280px;
        height: 100px;
        min-height: 100px;
        max-height: 100px;
    }
    .postbox img {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        object-fit: cover;
        top: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .postbox a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
```

My Function for postboxes (the description is the part I need to wrap)

```
echo "<div class='postbox'><p>";
                        echo $row['title']."<br>";
                        echo $row['date']."<br>";
                        echo $row['description']."<br>";
                        echo "<a href=view.php?user=".$userName."&post=".$postid.">•••</a>";
                        echo "</p>";
                        echo "</div>";
```

If you have any questions I will be more than happy to answer them.  Thank you.

Comment: You'll have fewer headaches with either [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) layouts.